# HTTP request to a page which is redirected to Another page in C#

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

i have a link http://www.example.com/dosend.aspx?send=008801719461643

When i tried this page in browser it parse the number(008801719461643) send in a java script response string http://www.example.com/hassent.aspx?mysqldbId=100 it will redirect to `hassent.aspx` by

window.location='http://www.example.com/hassent.aspx?mysqldbId=100' in `dosend.aspx` page.

In the `hassent.aspx` which has loged data in DB which mysqldbId=100(whcih is generated by `dosend.aspx`). and successfully sends sms in **008801719461643** .

When i request it by c#

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.example.com/dosend.aspx?send=008801719461643");

var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

var responseString = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
```

**responseString** contains html of `dosent.aspx` html with java script

```
<script>
window.location='http://www.example.com/hassent.aspx?mysqldbId=100 
</script>
```

No sms sent but request is still log to DB .In browser click URL sent sms but c# request does not. Is is possible to do it by C# application ? How?

Comment: Did you try sending another HttpWebRequest to `hassent.aspx?mysqldbId=100`?  Your server is doing the initial request, it might not work if the second request comes from a client's browser (different IP, etc)

Comment: I have parsed the **responseString** to get `mysqldbId` and give a another request by c# but does not send sms this time also

Comment: Make sure you carefully examine the responseStrings to see if you get anything indicating success or failure.

Comment: **responseString** got full html response with Status="OK" but no redirection to 'hassent.aspx?mysqldbId=100` by that page